# Does facebook video embed follow og:video redirect?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a page with a video on it .. say (http://example.com/123) and it provides all the og: meta tags for facebook... so when I make a post on FB with that url, facebook would automagically embed that video into the post.   open graph tags such as these:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This is a description." />
<meta property="og:video" content="https://example.com/player.swf?id=123&autoplay=on&blah=12345&etc"/>
<meta... etc. etc>
```

This works great.  However, I have a bunch of parameters on that swf player that I don't want facebook embed code to cache.  For example, i might have the parameter

```
autoplay=on
```

but if hardcode that into the og:video string, all videos embedded has autoplay turned on by default and would be hard to change.  Hence I want to have a level of indirection like:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://example.com/redirswf/123" />
```

where /redirswf/123 would redirect to the original full player.swf url

I tried this but when I post the url to FB, the video just doesn't play.  I'm not sure how to debug this.. all I can think of is that FB is not following the 302 redirect when it tries to go to redirswf/123?  can anyone confirm or deny?

And I did confirm via the facebook debugger tool that it's pulling out the og:video field as expected:

```
{
    "url": "https:\/\/example.com\/redirswf\/123",
    "secure_url": "https:\/\/example.com\/redirswf\/123",
    "type": "application\/x-shockwave-flash",
    "width": 640,
    "height": 360
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bleh, it's by design I guess =(
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/182548548598977